# could not find function "+<-"

Tags: ggplot2, ribbon

I get

> Error in ggplot(dfyear, aes(Years)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Low, ymax
> = High),  :    could not find function "+<-"

```
Years=1981:2020     
Low=runif(40,min=50,max=100)     
High=runif(40,100,200)     
ETFValue=(Low+High)/2     
dfyear=data.frame(Years,Low,High,ETFValue)          

ggplot(dfyear, aes(Years)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Low,ymax=High),fill="yellow") +
  ylab=("ETF value") +       
  geom_line(aes(y=ETFValue),size=2,col="darkblue")
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code -- you need to delete the `=` in your plot call. `ylab` is a function so the syntax should be `ylab()` not `ylab=`. `=` and `<-` are assignment operators, which is what the error is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
ylab=("ETF value") +
```

to this

```
ylab("ETF value") +
```

There isn't an `=` sign between function name and parentheses

Answer (score 1):

As a side note `size` is deprecated in newer versions of ggplot so you might want to use `linewidth` instead:

```r
ggplot(dfyear, aes(Years)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Low,ymax=High),fill="yellow") +
  ylab("ETF value") +       
  geom_line(aes(y=ETFValue),linewidth=2,col="darkblue") ## linewidth instead of size
```

Comment: This adds very little value as an answer since it does nothing to clearly identify the real problem, and even for that seems like a 3-day copy of the first answer (which is correct).